# Xamarin Forms to native & back query

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Following is the navigation stack I have in my app

page 1 (forms)-> Page 2(Native IOS with Page renderer) -> Another IOS native view via  UINavigationController (to select an image from photo galary & process it)-> Page 3 (forms)

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Page 1 in forms: Click on a button
2. Page 2 in IOS using page renderer

Code:

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
 {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var page = e.NewElement as DummyPage;
        AppDelegate.DummyPageRef = page;

        var view = NativeView;

        // create a new window instance based on the screen size
        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        viewController = new ImageViewController();

        navigationController = new UINavigationController();
        navigationController.PushViewController(viewController, false);

        // If you have defined a view, add it here:
        //window.AddSubview(navigationController.View);

        window.RootViewController = navigationController;

        // make the window visible
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        //var label = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, 40, 320, 40));
        //label.Text = "2 " + page.Heading;

        //view.Add(label);
}
```

3. ImageViewController page in IOS opens a galary for user to select an image, processes the selected image & when done processing calls page 3 on Forms with following

Code:

```
var secondViewController = App.GoToPostScanPage().CreateViewController();
NavigationController.PushViewController(secondViewController, true);
```

This works fine. But when I see the page 3 on forms the backstack is still pointing to my dynamic page that I created to select & process the image. How can I get rid of this IOS navigation stack & jump back to my Forms Navigation stack? Is this possible?

Thanks 
Supreet

Comment: Here is a sample code to show the issue at hand 
https://github.com/supreettare/Forms2Native2Forms

When you run the app you will see that when you from first Forms page to Second Native page, there is no navigation stack maintained & When you move from 2nd native page to 3rd forms page the Backstack has the link for the native page.. 
ideally all we need is a Page1->Page2->Page3 navigation where page 2 is rendered natively